# rails devise edit other users profiles as admin using devise's forms

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, admin

I'm trying to create admin roles that can go in and change other users information. I've already got everything set up pretty much except that I can't get the edit method to select the correct user to update.

Looking in the devise code, it looks like I need to update the resource to be the user of the profile that's being selected instead of the current user (which would be the admin).

How do I go about updating the resource that is sent into the devise edit view and update action? It looks like it might have something to do with this

```
 def authenticate_scope!
    send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", :force => true)
    self.resource = send(:"current_#{resource_name}")
 end
```

So for example, what I want to do is

```
def update_resource
    self.resource = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Is this possible?